# Problem with my VBS

Tags: windows-server-2003, vbscript

I'm trying to add a list of users from a xls file and I get this error:

```
Line: 6
Char: 5
Invalid Syntax
```

The script I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Scriptt/Users.xls")
intRow = 3
Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    Set objOU = GetObject("ou=REAL, dc=ormbunken, dc=com")
    Set objUser = objOU.Create _
        ("User", "cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value)
    objUser.sAMAccountName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    objUser.SetPassword = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 5).Value
    objUser.GivenName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
    objUser.SN = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value
    objUser.AccountDisabled = FALSE
    objUser.SetInfo
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop
objExcel.Quit
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Please read our FAQ so that you know what to post to which site.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to supply a protocol/server in the `GetObject` call? Like what this says

```
Set oOU = GetObject("LDAP://test.test.cz/ou=skup,dc=test,dc=test,dc=cz")
Set oUser = oOU.Create("User", "cn=" & "Test" & " " & "Tester")
```

taken from http://msdn.itags.org/iis/2649/

---

did a google, found http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/vbscript_user_spreadsheet.htm